# Cloning from HDD to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

I currently have HDD (500GB) with only 35GB used space. I want to clone the existing HDD to a new empty SSD (256GB). What's the easiest way to do that??

Comment: The easiest way is to copy all files by `cp -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the [Clonezilla live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) dvd when changing hard drives. It takes a little more effort when moving to a smaller disk but I know I have done it and assume I did something like the technique found at the following post
https://superuser.com/questions/1361361/clonezilla-wont-clone-to-a-smaller-disk